# LVM Mount Rescue Mode

Tags: mount, lvm, rescue

I am having trouble mounting a LVM to extract a Proxmox virtual machines data. Any ideas on how I can mount it?

```
root@rescue:~# mount /dev/sdd /mnt/
mount: block device /dev/sdd is write-protected, mounting read-only
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdd': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdd' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
root@rescue:~# mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt/
mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'
root@rescue:~#
```

Disk info

```
root@rescue:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 240.1 GB, 240057409536 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 29185 cylinders, total 468862128 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000bf890

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        4096    40962047    20478976   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        40962048    43057151     1047552   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3        43057152   468854783   212898816    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5        43059200   468854783   212897792   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 765633 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x35f0e73a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdd: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 765633 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x43bc6360

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 240.1 GB, 240057409536 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91879 cylinders, total 468862128 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xf95db8ab

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   468862127   234430040   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/pve-data: 453.8 GB, 453760778240 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 55166 cylinders, total 886251520 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/pve-data doesn't contain a valid partition table
root@rescue:~#
```

[image]

Comment: do you have the `lvm2` tools installed?  if not, then that's the first thing you need to do.  it's available pre-packaged for most distros...e.g. on debian, run `apt-get install lvm2`

Comment: Yes it's installed

Answer (score 1):

That partition has the type “Linux LVM”, so it is presumably an LVM physical volume. Use `file -s /dev/sdd1` to check.

Run the command `pvs` to see a summary of the physical volumes that are available on your system, or `pvdisplay` to see more detailed information. If you think that some physical volumes are present but not detected, run `pvscan` to scan all connected disks for potential LVM volumes.

In the `VG` column of the `pvs` output, you see the volume group to which the physical volume belongs to. If a volume group is spread over multiple physical volumes, all physical volumes need to be present (except in RAID appropriate configurations). Run `vgs` to see a summary of the available volume groups, or `vgdisplay` to see more detailed information.

The content of LVM areas is accessed through logical volumes. Run `lvs` to see a summary of the available volume groups, or `lvdisplay` to see more detailed information. In order to access a logical volume, it must be active, which `lvs` reports with an `a` in the “Attr” column. If the volume hasn't been activated automatically, do so with `lvchange -ay mygroup/myvolume` where `mygroup` is the volume group name and `myvolume` is the logical volume name. You can also use `vgchange -ay mygroup` to activate all the logical volumes in a group.

To mount an active logical volume, refer to it by its device path, which is `/dev/mapper/mygroup-myvolume` or `/dev/mygroup/myvolume`.